# Using image styles and term references

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, media

I have a taxonomy called sponsors with an image field attached. Then I have a content type with a field-collection and inside of the field collection I have the term reference.  So when the admin creates a content type they can choose a sponsor and I setup a view to show the image.  However, they would like to have 3 different sizes to choose from when creating the content.  Is it possible to provide them with a choice of image styles almost like the Insert module let's you do?

**UPDATE**:  Looks like it's going to be custom code.  The formatter module is nice, but it does not suite the needs for my particular use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Formatter Field](http://drupal.org/project/formatter_field) module was made for just that:

> The formatter field module provides a mechanism for specifying a formatter and formatter settings to be used for displaying a field, on a per-entity basis. By default, Drupal provides formatters and settings per entity bundle, but in certain situations it is necessary to choose the formatter at the entity level.
>
> For example, say you have a page node with an image field. Normally, you would select an image style as the formatter, and all page nodes would use that same image style. With this module, you can add a formatter field to page nodes, which is hooked up to the image field. Then when the node is created or edited, the image style can be selected per-node.

There are some steps on the module page I'd recommend reading before diving right in, it's not immediately obvious how to make this module work.

Comment: This looks very handy - cheers!

Comment: @coleopterist I just tried to look up Barsoom on Google maps thanks to your profile. Now I feel stupid ;)

Comment: haha! Google Earth might have been a better bet as it has a 'Mars' option :D

Comment: When it says add Formatter field to the entity bundle does that mean add a field to the vocabulary and what does it mean by Formatter field?

Comment: Once you've installed the module you should have a new field type called 'Formatter field'. Add a new one of those to your vocabulary, then on the settings page for the field, choose the image field as the one it should reference. When you add/edit some content you should get the image style options next to/below the image

Comment: Doh.. Enabling the module might help...  Thanks Clive checking it out now.

Comment: Ok it looks like this will work for them to choose when they are creating an actual taxonomy term and adding an image to the term.  What I am looking for is when they are creating content not a term and there is a list of all of the sponsors to tag the node with they can choose what to tag it with and what the formatter should be.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry missed your last comment somehow. I don't think you'll find a contrib module that does exactly that as it's a very specific use case; you'll probably have to resort to custom code to be honest

Comment: Any thoughts on a direction for the custom code?